# How to use Record Utility in typescript?

Tags: typescript, mongodb

I am trying to map an instance with any for all properties (as params of func)
In the body of the function, everything may be okay. But the IDE shows an error when I use this func

`Argument of type '{ category: Types.ObjectId | { $exist: boolean; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<keyof Product, any>'.`

```
@ObjectType()
export class Product {
  @Field(() => ID)
  id: string

  @Prop({ required: true })
  @Field(() => String)
  name: string

  // Other properties  
 
}
```

```
  async find(filter: Record<keyof Product, any>, options: FilterOffet) {
    //
  }
```

```
 @Query(() => [Product], { name: 'products' })
  async find(
    // some params
  ) {
    return this.productService.find(
      { category: filter.category || { $exist: true } },
      filter
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, it is my fault just change `Record<keyof Product, any>` to `Partial<Record<keyof Product, any>>`